# Nuxt in IE - using sticky

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, nuxt.js

In essense,I'm trying to make an element that floats sticky. 
I've been through a few packages but "vue-stickykit" matches all of my demands for it, however it doesn't work in IE11.

I get a 

`SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'`

in the console

and everything stops. It's vue-stickykit internal install command that throws the error - is there any way to work around it?

Comment: the workaround is to avoid IE. Switch to Edge, Chrome, Firefox instead.

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about the sticky then it is not supported in Internet Explorer.

So if Vue JS is using it in its code then this can be the reason for your issue.

[image]

Reference:

[position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

You can try to make a test with MS Edge browser. It is supports sticky.

Also try to provide a sample code. We will check it with IE and test it on our side.

Other thing you had mentioned that **it is internal install command of vue js that throw the error**. In that case you need to ask support from Vue Js because we don't know about the mechanism of Vue Js and how it get installed.

Comment: Okay - I read the src code a little more and found a solution for the package problems. A PR has been sent. 

The reason it failed was the package used a shorthand method which wasn't in reach of my polyfill.